# Input Simulator error for Surface 2.0 SDK

Tags: pixelsense

This might be esoteric but here goes.

I'm developing a program in WPF for use on a multitouch screen.  I'm using the Surface 2.0 SDK and trying to get the Toolkit to simulate inputs and run the stress test.  However `SurfaceStress.exe` is throwing an error:

```
Error 0: Cannot get reference to virtual digitizer controller.
```

and Input Simulator is giving me a timeout error looking for the controller.

I've read up about it on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727911.aspx

I know it can't run two controllers at the same time and it's not on a SUR40.  It says "Tablet PC Settings" would only appear if the Input Simulator is running.  But it's running anyway and its Setup button is grayed out.  I don't have a touchscreen but I do have a Wacom Bamboo tablet connected.  Has anyone else had interference between a tablet and Surface Input Simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in Device Manager.  Bamboo touch drivers disabled the Virtual Digitizer Controller which was also listed as a device. Flip the switches and rode off into the sunset. good job, me! o/